# CakePHP checkboxes - ignore unselected checkboxes

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

This should hopefully be a nice simple question.

On a form I have a number of checkboxes relating to selecting various users for a particular function.  The checkbox is created like so

```
$this->Form->input("user_select", array(
  "type"   => "checkbox",
  "name"   => "data[Registration][User][]",
  "id"     => "UserId" . $user['User']['id'],
  "value"  => $user['User']['id'],
  "label"  => false
));
```

When this form is submitted it comes through to the registration controller but the request->data array contains the checkboxes that aren't selected too in the format:

```
array(
  'Registration' => array(
    'Users' => array(
      (int) 0 => '0',
      (int) 1 => '0',
      (int) 2 => '0',
      (int) 3 => '0',
      (int) 4 => '31',
      (int) 5 => '0',
      (int) 6 => '11'
    ),
)
```

Now there's nothing wrong with the data, its clear to see that user's 31 and 11 have been selected but I'd much prefer an array of the form:

```
array(
  'Registration' => array(
    'Users' => array(
      (int) 4 => '31',
      (int) 6 => '11'
    ),
)
```

This would make processing and validation much much easier.

So, **Does CakePHP have a facility to prevent unselected checkboxes being shown in the request->data array?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `'hiddenField' => false` to your input() call:

```
$this->Form->input("user_select", array(
  "type"        => "checkbox",
  "name"        => "data[Registration][User][]",
  "id"          => "UserId" . $user['User']['id'],
  "value"       => $user['User']['id'],
  "label"       => false,
  "hiddenField" => false
));
```

CakePHP will automatically add a hidden field unless you tell it not to, presumably so that all of the form's keys are represented in `$this->data->request`. Check [this page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html) for more information.

Comment: Lovely job there, that's exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

Commiting form will always return all checkboxes wheter they are checked or not, It's up to you to decide what to do with this data. As far as I know CakePHP has no such functionality you are asking for, but you can always use PHP to unset empty elements...

```
 foreach( $array as $key => $val ) {
   if( empty($val) ) {
     unset( $array[$key] );
   }
 }
```

Comment: That's what I have been doing but I'd like a cleaner more generic solution if one exists.